# Using Handsontable with JSF

Tags: jsf, handsontable

Does anyone have experience with an jsf implemented handsontable? Is that even possible? 
 I'd appreciate some brabbling!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a wrapper for handsontable in JSF. Implementing such a wrapper for limited features is fairly simple, but this will really get complex and time consuming if you want to handle all callback hooks with AJAX.

An alternative may be [Primefaces dataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml).

Comment: Too bad, I already thought so. Sadly all of those complex-making AJAX-hooks are the ones I need in order to copy/paste from excel or calc tables.

Primefaces dataTabel doesn't support this function, sadly. Thank you for the alternative anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, make a link as follows:

xhtml

```
<h:inputHidden id="import_json_data" value="#{managedBean.json_data}" />
<p:commandButton value="Import Data" onstart="loadJson()" actionListener="#{managedBean.importData()}" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function loadJson() {
    var varieties = $('#value_table').data('handsontable').getData();
    var varieties_data = JSON.stringify(varieties);
    $('#import_json_data').val(varieties_data);
  }

  function fillHandsontable() {
    var data = [ [ "", "", ""] ];
    var $container = $("#value_table");
    $container.handsontable({
      data : data,
    });
   };

  fillHandsontable();
</script>
```

ManagedBean

```
private String json_data; //getters and setters

public void importData() {
  System.out.println(this.json_data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found one [Here](https://code.google.com/p/jsf-sheet/)
and a here is a working [DEMO](http://server.stickysession.com/jsfdemo/demo.jsf)